# moving files with patron in directories to specific directory

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I got a bunch of directories with names like (I cannot change anything about go this are generated):

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR1 File 01 random_number/    
yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR2 File 06 random_number/
yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR3 File 11 random_number/
etc
```

where `random_number` is a 11 digit random integer. Every directory has a file named `something.ext` (the same name for every one). There is also a directory called `done` where I move the directories that I already processed.

I rename the `something.ext` files and copy them to another directory, manually like this:

```
cd yyyy-MM-dd\ hh.mm.ss\ DIR1\ File\ 01\ random_number/
mv something.ext File\ 01.ext
cp File\ 01.ext /path/to/DIR1/
cd ..
mv yyyy-MM-dd\ hh.mm.ss\ DIR1\ File\ 01\ random_number/ done/

cd yyyy-MM-dd\ hh.mm.ss\ DIR2\ File\ 06\ random_number/
mv something.ext File\ 06.ext
cp File\ 06.ext /path/to/DIR2/
cd ..
mv yyyy-MM-dd\ hh.mm.ss\ DIR2\ File\ 06\ random_number/ done/

etc
```

Is there any way i can automate this through a script? I'm not really good filtering names and stuff... I'm familiar with bash and python scripting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `=~` operator for regex pattern matching inside a for loop, which has been a feature of bash starting from `bashv3+`. A [subshell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442692/is-a-subshell#442704) is useful when using `cd` and not worrying if and when you need to exit the current directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

regex='^(.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+)$'

for directory in */; do
  if [[ $directory =~ $regex ]]; then
    dir_num0="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    dir_num1="${BASH_REMATCH[4]} ${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
    (
      printf 'Going inside directory [%s]\n' "$directory" 
      cd "$directory" || exit
      echo mv -v -- something.txt "$dir_num1.ext" || exit
      echo cp -v -- "$dir_num1.ext" "/path/to/$dir_num0" || exit
    )
    echo mv -v -- "$directory" done/ || exit
  fi
done
```

---

With your given sample input/data the output is:

```
Going inside directory [xxx-xx-xx xx.xx.xx DIR3 File 11 x/]
mv -v -- something.txt File 11.ext
cp -v -- File 11.ext /path/to/DIR3
mv -v -- xxx-xx-xx xx.xx.xx DIR3 File 11 x/ done/
Going inside directory [xxx-xx-xx xx.xx.xx DIR1 File 01 xx/]
mv -v -- something.txt File 01.ext
cp -v -- File 01.ext /path/to/DIR1
mv -v -- xxxx-xx-xx xx.xx.xx DIR1 File 01 x/ done/
Going inside directory [xxxx-xx-xx xx.xx.xx DIR2 File 06 x/]
mv -v -- something.txt File 06.ext
cp -v -- File 06.ext /path/to/DIR2
mv -v -- xxxx-xx-xx xx.xx.xx DIR2 File 06 x/ done/
```

---

- The `=~` test/regex operator supports [E.R.E](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html)
- Place the script inside the directory in question and execute it. Or place the script within your `PATH` and go inside the top directory of the files/directories in question.
- Remove the `echo`'s if you're satisfied with the output.
- The regex/pattern `regex='^(.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+) (.+)$'` matches 6 fields with a space as the delimiter/separator. It can be made more specific to your directory names.

---

Something like

```
regex='^([[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}) ([[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]]{2}) (.+) (.+) ([[:digit:]]+) ([[:digit:]]+)/$'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!!!...  I'm getting 2 results on the terminal (echo), one correct: ´mv -v -- .txt .ext; cp -v -- File 01.ext /path/to/DIR1´ y the other one like this: ´mv -v -- something.txt .ext; cp -v -- .ext /path/to/DIR1´... I think we have to exclude the directory ´done' from the list the script is looping...

Comment: I found a work around, all directories of interest start with 2021-, so I just edited the for to ´for directory in 2021*/´, but if there are directories from other years I wouldn't know how to fixed it...

Comment: Right, I forgot the last `mv` . I have updated the answer please try it now.

Comment: `2021-*/` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that all you have in the initial directory is your "bunch of directories" plus the done directory. Also, for testing purposes, I made the `/path/to/` equal to `./done/` so that `/path/to/DIR1/` is equal to `./done/DIR1/`, `/path/to/DIR2/` is equal to `./done/DIR2/`, and so on. My test directory tree looks like this:

```
$ find .
.
./done
./done/DIR1
./done/DIR2
./done/DIR3
./yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR3 File 11 random_number
./yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR3 File 11 random_number/something.ext
./yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR2 File 06 random_number
./yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR2 File 06 random_number/something.ext
./yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR1 File 01 random_number
./yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR1 File 01 random_number/something.ext
$
```

You can achieve your `mv`s and `cp`s with a simple bash loop like this:

```
for i in *; do
    if [ "$i" == "done" ]; then
        continue;
    fi;
    file=$(echo $i | awk '{print $4 " " $5}').ext;
    todir=./done/$(echo $i | awk '{print $3}');
    mv "$i/something.ext" "$i/$file";
    cp "$i/$file" "$todir";
    mv "$i" done;
done
```

Here is the directory tree and files after running the script:

```
$ find .
.
./done
./done/DIR1
./done/DIR1/File 01.ext
./done/DIR2
./done/DIR2/File 06.ext
./done/DIR3
./done/DIR3/File 11.ext
./done/yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR1 File 01 random_number
./done/yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR1 File 01 random_number/File 01.ext
./done/yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR2 File 06 random_number
./done/yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR2 File 06 random_number/File 06.ext
./done/yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR3 File 11 random_number
./done/yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss DIR3 File 11 random_number/File 11.ext
$
```

Comment: thanks!! not exactly, but I can adapt it to my needs